# PARAMETERIS Parameterise Linked Service in Azure Data Factory for varied Source

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to create a parametrised Linked Service in Azure Data Factory. 
Source system includes the following :
a) SFTP Server
b) SAP Hana
c) SFDC
d) Oracle
Sink includes the following:
a) ADLS (gen2)
b) Azure SQL DB/DWH
c) Azure Analysis service.

I want to store the configuration details like Server Name, Port, User/Pwd in a text file and this will be read for fetching the details of each source and sink.

Can you please help me with this. If this can be achieved or we need to have this manually each time.

I want to create a parametrised Linked Service in Azure Data Factory. 
Source system includes the following :
a) SFTP Server
b) SAP Hana
c) SFDC
d) Oracle
Sink includes the following:
a) ADLS (gen2)
b) Azure SQL DB/DWH
c) Azure Analysis service.

I want to store the configuration details like Server Name, Port, User/Pwd in a text file and this will be read for fetching the details of each source and sink.

Can you please help me with this. If this can be achieved or we need to have this manually each time.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your credentials in a text file is a *very risky* idea in terms of security.  May I suggest using Azure Key Vault?  This is a [recommended way to store and reference your credentials for use in Azure Data Factory V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault).  Even if the UI does not display Azure Key Vault as an option, you can still [utilize it by altering the JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services#json).

If you still prefer to use a text file, it is possible, but unwieldy.  You would use a Lookup activity on your text file, and then place the output into an array type variable.  I reccomend you write your text file in JSON format, in order to leverage the string-to-JSON-object function in a dynamic expression to transform the contents into a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Martin. So this is possible with Data Sources like SAP Hana, SFDC as well as SFTP.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes.  I do not have any SAP instances to test against, so let me know if it doesn't work.